# High chart not display in asp.net mvc4

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, highcharts

i try to use highchart js.and this is a tutoroui web (How to use Highchart Js).And my problem is the chart can not display in my view .Can you tell me and how can i do . Thank you so much

this is my code from Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DotNet.Highcharts;
using DotNet.Highcharts.Helpers;
using DotNet.Highcharts.Options;
using DotNet.Highcharts.Enums;

namespace NiceHighChart.Controllers
{
public class IndexController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Index/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart").SetXAxis(
            new XAxis
            {
                Categories = new[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr" }
            }).SetSeries(new Series
            {
                Data = new Data(new object[]{
                       29.2, 50.1, 87.4, 91.9
                })
            });
        return View(chart);
    }

}
}
```

And this is my view

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/masterPage.Master"  Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

      <h2>Index</h2>

      <br />

<asp:Literal ID="ltrChart" runat="server"></asp:Literal>

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
```

And this is my Master page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="masterPage.master.cs" Inherits="NiceHighChart.Views.Shared.masterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Nice HighChart</title>
<script src="../../Scripts/Highcharts-3.0.1/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js"></script>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</head>
<body>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Result::

[image: This is a result]

Comment: are you sure js scripts url is right?

Comment: Errors from JavaScript console would be great.

Comment: sure?? .Not have something wrong about url js path .because i'm pull the js file to my code in master page.

Comment: Attach errors from JS console then we will help you more, otherwise we can only guess..

Comment: not have some error about js console Pawel Fus